# Browser Hints- Preconnect - can it hurt load performance?

Tags: performance, browser

i have a site with more than 20 tags.
almost each tag with a different domain.
i'm thinking of adding a link with rel="preconnect" to all of them.

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="//cdn.example.com" crossorigin>
```

does it make sense? can performance decrease from that?

also, does it make sense to add it from client side?

```
<script> 
var res = document.createElement("link"); 
res.rel = "preconnect"; 
res.href = "//cdn.example.com"; 
document.head.appendChild(res); 
</script>
```